# In handleSubmit method, setState is not updating my details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a basic Form. While submitting the form in my `handleSubmit` method, I'm callling a `setState` method which has the details object I am trying to update. However, the details object is not getting updated.

Kindly help me to understand the problem and resolve it. Thanks in advance...

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    array: [],
    
    details: {
      name: '',
      phonenumber: '',
      company: '',
      email: '',
    }
  };
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.details);
  this.setState({
    array: [...this.state.array,this.state.details],
    details: {
      name: '',
      phonenumber: '',
      company: '',
      email: '',
    }
  });
}

handleDetails = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    details: {
      ...this.state.details,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: You don't update `details` in `handleSubmit`, you do so in `handleDetails`

Comment: Could you give us more details? Like, your submit function or explain in what moment that you see your state still the same.

Comment: Why would you update the state in handleSubmit? You should do it in your other function